# jQuery Div Scrolling Function: Issue in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, styling

I'm currently developing a website that that has a fixed banner div that is centered, and I'm using the jQuery below to ensure that it scrolls correctly even though it is a fixed positioned div.

jQuery:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

    $('#top-content').css('left', -$(this).scrollLeft() + "px");

});
```

However, I have come across an issue within IE(version 9). The issue is that when the user scrolls the website (creating a minus left margin on the "top-content" div, to give the effect of scrolling) and then if they maximize the webpage, the left margin is still present causing the div to not be centered.

I have attempted to remedy this with the jQuery below, but as of yet no luck

```
$(window).resize(function() {

    if ($("#top-content").width() < $(window).width()) {

        $('#top-content').css('left:0px');

    }   

});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You better do

```
$('#top-content').css('left', '0px');
```

In your resize event.